# height: 100% to use the remaining height?

Tags: html, css

The red is the header.
Then I have 5 rows, where I want to let use each 20% of the remaining space.
But instead it takes 20% of the window space. How can this be fixed?

[image]

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="items">
        <div class="item" id="item1"></div>
        <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
        <div class="item" id="item3"></div>
        <div class="item" id="item4"></div>
        <div class="item" id="item5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}

#items {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.item {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}

#item1 {
    background: green;
}

#item2 {
    background: blue;
}

#item3 {
    background: orange;
}

#item4 {
    background: purple;
}

#item5 {
    background: brown;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/dabrm8js/

Comment: It already take 20% of remaining space.

Comment: lol it was red(read)..yes its already taking 20% space..then what's the issue?

Comment: I agree it already take 20% of the remaining space. Your html take 100% of the window height and your container 100% of the html height.

Comment: css sucks. My header can change in height. Now I have to use a tons of media queries...

Answer (score 2):

```
#items {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

10% is taken by header, so you have 90% of height for items (and not all 100%)...

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of your items div to 90%. 
Next to the header (10%) they will fill the screen. Then the .item divs will each take up to 20% of their parent (#items).

So try

`#items {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS tables.

1) Set `display:table` on the container and give it a background color (this will be the color of the header)

2) Set `display:table-row` on the header and items

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dabrm8js/2/)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#header {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
#items {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
.item {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}
#item1 {
  background: green;
}
#item2 {
  background: blue;
}
#item3 {
  background: orange;
}
#item4 {
  background: purple;
}
#item5 {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="items">
    <div class="item" id="item1"></div>
    <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
    <div class="item" id="item3"></div>
    <div class="item" id="item4"></div>
    <div class="item" id="item5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

NB: If CSS3 is an option this can also be done with flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use flex boxes for this:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* fixed height */
  min-height: 10%;  /* you don't need this? */ 
}

#items {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* take the remaining height (grow) */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* distribute height equally, 20% height for 5 rows, 25% for 4 etc. */
}
```

([test](http://jsfiddle.net/kLm1f12z/))

For older browsers support you need to add prefixed version of the properties and the older properties (like `box-orient`)

Tables may do the job too, if you can live with their limitations with padding, margins and positioning

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm working on it now to understand all aspects. What I don't get, why is it 'flex-direction: column;' for the container? For me it makes more sense if that would be row since first there is the header and then under that there is the div that hold all items.

Comment: Does flex interfere with hover? For some reason my hover not works here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623028/hover-not-working-is-this-due-to-flex-properties

Comment: "row"  means that the flexbox items are layed out horizontally, in a single row. There's also a `flex-wrap` property that allows you to break them across multiple rows if they don't fit. But it looks like you just want your divs one below the other, in one "column".  Your `:hover` rule is not applied because the rules where you set a background based on the ID have higher priority

Answer (score 0):

Height of items need to be 90% as 10% is already used by header part.